# PathFileExists causes Linker error 2028/2019

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-7-x64

trying out PathFileExists as explainded here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx 
causes Linker-Errors LNK2028 and LNK2019.
Here is my code:

```
char buffer1[] = "C:\\temp\\index.xml";
char *lpStr1;
lpStr1 = buffer1;

int retval;

retval = PathFileExistsA(lpStr1);
if (retval == 1 )
{
    this->lbl_stat->Text = "File found!";
}else{
    this->lbl_stat->Text = "File not found!";
}
```

Comment: Add Shlwapi.lib to the list of linker dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

As explained at the bottom of the MSDN page, you have to add to the project properties the dependency towards shlwapi.lib (look for "additional libraries" or something like that under the linker settings).